# Why the customized Filter Chips, from Material Design in XAML, are not working?

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

According to the documentation of the Material Design in XAML, I should be able to do something like this:

```
<ListBox
  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilterChipPrimaryOutlineListBox}">
  <ListBoxItem>
  Mercury
</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem
    IsSelected="True">
  Venus
</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>
  Earth
</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem
    IsEnabled="False">
  Pluto
</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

I'm building a WPF application, and the compilator cannot find the `Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilterChipPrimaryOutlineListBox}"`

The `Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilterChipListBox}"` is working just fine, but any of the other customized chips are not working.

Here is my App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Proav.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Proav"
             xmlns:dragablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz;assembly=Dragablz"             
             StartupUri="Login.xaml"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"            
             >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- primary color -->
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <!-- include your primary palette -->
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <materialDesign:BundledTheme PrimaryColor="Amber" SecondaryColor="Indigo"  BaseTheme="Light" />
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary>

                <!-- Include the Dragablz Material Design style -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dragablz;component/Themes/materialdesign.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- tell Dragablz tab control to use the Material Design theme -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabablzControlStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have tried to add the
`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Chip.xaml" />` into the Merged Dictionaries but didn't work.

Comment: How can we ever help you finding an issue in a code you didn't show??? We don't know where you keep your `MaterialDesignFilterChipPrimaryOutlineListBox` and if it's visible in your xaml.

Comment: A tip: load all your custom styles at startup. Merge them in App.xaml, where you already have your MaterialDesign resource dictionaries. This way these styles will always be visible.

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski Don't be like that, you're not helping anybody being agressive. And I'm already doing that, I've tried in the App.xaml and in the UserControlClient.xaml (which is the window where I'm trying to use the code).

Comment: Thanks for showing more details of your code.

Answer (score 0):

With the Material Design in XAML library there are the default styles that are loaded when you include the MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml resource dictionary (as you have done in your App.xaml) and then there are additional styles that require you to reference an additional resource dictionary. These additional resource dictionaries are named to match the control that they get applied to.

So in this case the MaterialDesignFilterChipPrimaryOutlineListBox style is an optional style in the MaterialDesignTheme.ListBox.xaml resource dictionary. So to find it you need to include the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Chip.xaml" />
```

There is more information about this situation on the [project's wiki page](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/FAQ#exception-cannot-find-resource-named-materialdesign) as well.